# How do you say 'I had to brush up on my Spanish quick' or 'I had to remember my Spanish quickly?'

Tags: traducción, gramática

The door man greeted me in Spanish. **I had to brush on my Spanish quick**

It would be written as English followed by Spanish to show a shift in language:

The door man greeted me in Spanish. *Spanish sentence here.*

Both Mexican Spanish or Castillian Spanish examples if possible. Gracias!

Comment: *I don't think your English is accurate*. If someone speaks to you, you can't brush up on a language immediately. However, "When I went to Mexico, I had to brush up on my Spanish".

Answer (score 1):

El portero me saludó en español.

> The door man greeted me in Spanish.

Tuve que repasar mi español rápido

> I had to brush up on my Spanish quick.

En español existen distintos modos de expresar la misma oración. Estos son algunos ejemplos.

- tuve que refrescar mi español rápidamente.
- tuve que desempolvar rápidamente mi español.
- tuve que repasar mi español rápidamente.
- tuve que repasar mi oxidado español rápidamente.
- tuve que hacer una rápida puesta a punto de mi español.

> In Spanish there are different ways of expressing the same sentence.
> These are some examples.
>
> - I had to refresh my Spanish quickly.
> - I had to quickly dust off my Spanish
> - I had to brush up on my rusty Spanish quickly.
> - I had to review my Spanish quickly.
>
> ---
>
> ---

---

En esta frase, para indicar lo mismo, no hay grandes variaciones entre el español de España y el de México a no ser que se utilice jerga específica.

> In this sentence, to indicate the same thing, there are no great
> variations between the Spanish of Spain and that of Mexico unless
> specific jargon (slang) is used.

Comment: +1 Me gustó especialmente "desempolvar".

Comment: Diego, all those examples in English are translations and not all are accurate. Also, some of those sentences are not great in English.

Comment: Lambie, eso pensé. Si eres tan amable o bien pueden editarlo y cambiar lo que consideres o bien, me escribes las oraciones correctamente para quitar las erradas. Gracias por estar atento.

Comment: @Diego ‘A quick tune up’ sounds very odd, I don’t see it as ever being used in this context.

Comment: The OP needs to redo the question with correct English. :)